# Can a Matrix table be forced to scroll horizontally to allow for usable column widths?

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

So I have way too many columns, let's get that out of the way first. But, be that as it may, I find that entering Matrix field data on a 13' laptop to be quite cramped.

Here's a sample of what it looks like on my 27" iMac.
[image: Matrix field stretched out on iMac display]

Nice, plenty of room to edit all fields.

Now let's look at that same field on a much smaller screen.

[image: Matrix field scrunched up]

Most of it is tedious to work with at this width.

What I'd really like is if the Matrix field would automatically stretch to be as wide as it needs to be, and the containing DIV would just scroll horizontally to accommodate it.

Has anyone encountered, and found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This may not work exactly the way you want but it's a solution:

When setting up your Matrix columns set a Column Width. This will force the width of the column.

[image]

Then create a new file called override.css and place it into your EE install here:
`/themes/cp_themes/default/css/`

In that file add:

```
table.matrix {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```